# How i write an advanced function to delete file from a specific folder if file size greater then specified size in Kb

Tags: powershell, function, delete-file

```
function Sort-Size { 
    <# 
    .SYNOPSIS 
        Wait untill condition persists 
    .DESCRIPTION 
        The function allows you to wait for a time, while the condition is cheked 
    .NOTES 
        Information or caveats about the function e.g. 'This function is not supported in Linux' 
    .LINK 
        Specify a URI to a help page, this will show when Get-Help -Online is used. 
    .EXAMPLE 
        PS C:\> Wait-Condition -Condition {<Condition>} -CheckEvery 5 -Timeout 30 
    #> 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [scriptblock]$Condition, 
 
        [Parameter()] 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [int]$Lenght = 1024 ## kb
 
    ) 
     
    begin { 
        $PSDefaultParameterValues = @{Name='FileSizeInKb';Expression={$_.Length/1KB}
        $timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new() 
    } 
     
    process { 
        #Keep in the loop while condition is checking 
        Write-Verbose -Message "Start sorting..." 
        While (& $Condition) { 
            Write-Verbose -Message "Waiting for sorting..." 
            If ($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -ge $Timeout) { 
                throw "Timeout execeed. Giving up..." 
            } 
            #Stop the loop every $CheckEvery second 
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $CheckEvery 
        } 
    } 
     
    end { 
        $timer.Stop() 
    } 
} 
 
Sort-Size "Wait-Condition" 

Sort-Size -Condition {Test-Path -Path "C:\test\1.txt"}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to write a function correctly

Comment: How does your question in the title relates to the function you're showing us? I assume you want to query the same dir until the size is above `.Length` and then remove but its not really clear

Comment: Also a FileSystemWatcher makes more sense for that than this function